# To be into something vs favor something

Tags: verbs, verb-usage

Suppose you like something like Pop music; which one of the following self-made sentences would sound more natural to you if you want to say that you like pop music more than every other musical genres:

> - I'm into pop music.
> - I favor pop music.

For me, they both work and mean the same.

I made a similar question somewhere else. I got to this point that they mean the same and the only difference is that "favor" is a bit antiquated and "to be into" is very colloquial / informal. But what I am looking for is a verb which does not make the listener get surprised. I need a normal verb. I guess some other structures would work here instead of the above ones (like: like sth better than sth else), but whereas the sentences would require some more explanation, I doubt if it is a correct way to describe the same thing! Please have a note on the following self-made sentence:

> I like pop music better **than all other music genres**

Without the bold part (extra explanation) my sentence would not mean the same as the sentences which are using "favor" or "be into"!

Comment: Can you provide dictionary definitions that back up your claim that the meanings are the same?

Comment: In this particular context, the two usages convey the same meaning. In another context, _being into sth_ and _favoring sth_ might not convey the same meaning.

Comment: @JavaLatte once I asked a native speaker. Sometimes some points in contemporary language (especially AE) cannot be found in any particular dictionary.

Comment: @A-friend, look at this dictionary definition https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/favour. Which meaning do you think might have the same meaning as **be into**?

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences have different meanings

> I favor pop music.

means you *like* pop music and given a choice you would rather hear pop music over classical or rock or hip-hop music.

> I'm into pop music.

also means you enjoy pop music but have a deeper interest in it than merely *favoring* it.  You might perform pop music yourself, or study pop music as a subject.

"To favor *something*" is to be next to the pool, to "be into *something*" is to jump in the pool.

Comment: Is it applicable for someone like e.g. a girl from among several girlfriends of you or something like a shirt which you like it?

Comment: Also, as far as I know, “to favor sb / sth” is antiquated and “to be into sb / sth” is very colloquial. In neutral speech native speakers probably would use some other structures like: “like better / more than sb / sth” or "prefer over etc". Do you confirm it?

Comment: I wouldn't use "favor" or "into" to describe relationships, if one were to say "I'm really into Candice" it might be taken the wrong way as in *something* sexual. I also wouldn't necessarily say "favors" is antiquated, "The referee *favors* the home team", one could also use "The referee *is biased towards*.